# How to link in -lpthread -lm -ldl in CMake

Tags: cmake, intel-mkl

I am trying to use cmake to link intel mkl for my code. From mkl link advisor, I should link the library by:

```
 -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_sequential -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

I then write a module to find `mkl_intel_lp64`, `mkl_core`, and `mkl_sequential` in Findmkl.cmake:

```
find_library(lp64_libraries NAMES mkl_intel_lp64 PATHS "${mkl_path}/lib/intel64")
find_library(core_libraries NAMES mkl_core PATHS "${mkl_path}/lib/intel64")
find_library(sequential_libraries NAMES mkl_sequential PATHS "${mkl_path}/lib/intel64")
```

Then I can link these libraries. While I do not know how to link `-lpthread -lm -ldl`, I am not sure what this link mean, I can not find any libpthread.a in $MKLROOT/lib/intel64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those libraries should exist on each Unix system.

So you can just add:

```
target_link_libraries(target_name m dl pthread)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, David. I tried this, it works. While I need slightly more in practice. My code has a lot of libraries, I use `set(lib_all ${mkl_libraries} ${lib_all})` to add mkl, use `set(lib_all ${gmp_libraries} ${lib_all})` to link gmp, after link many libraries, then use: target_link_libraries(target_name ${lib_all}). I prefer to put `m dl pthread` in mkl_libraries instead of target_link_libraries(target_name ${lib_all} m dl pthread). Is there a way to add `m dl pthread`  to mkl_libraries?